# How to record video using Camera2 API in SceneForm

Tags: android, android-camera2, sceneform

Using Android sceneform I am developing an application, I know that currently we don't have an option to record a video with rendered 3d Objects but is there any option to record a camera data's just like we are doing normal camera video recording ([Google Android video record sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video))?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class to record the rendered 3d objects in your Sceneform project:

https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/videorecording/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/videorecording/VideoRecorder.java